# Threshold for starting/quitting/etc. is high / There is high bar for starting/etc

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

Firstly, I guess the phrases in the title are wrong, but it is difficult for me to formulate the question because I am trying to find a way to express something like in the title but I do not know how to say it correctly in English.
Let's say I have a task waiting to be started, but to do the work requires a lot of concentration and effort, so I have to be able to change the state of mind and really toughen myself, physically or mentally or both. Instead of starting, it could be also a matter of quitting, for example to resign a job that I have had for a long time, or quit smoking etc. So, I am just trying to find a generic expression like in the title that describes that there is a high threshold, or high bar, that needs to be overcome in order to do the thing.

Of course I have tried to Google the expression, but the closest thing I have found is "setting a high bar" and I feel it is not a good way to express what I want. For example, could I say "I have set myself a high bar for quitting smoking"? I feel it does not express the idea properly because I have not **set** bar high, the bar just **is** high. So, could I say "The bar/threshold for quitting smoking is high for me"? I could not find any example that would use such an expression.
If you think there is much better way to express that particular sentence, can you also apply that to "quitting a job" or "starting a new task" or "running for President" ? So, I am trying to find a generic expression for these kind of situations, not specific expressions for some particular cases.

Edit: I am asking for a generic phrase because in my native language (Finnish) there is a generic expression for this (it goes actually literally like "threshold is high for starting to do blah blah"), and I am just wondering whether there is such a phrase also in English. But if there is none, then that is the answer I am looking for. So, if you are sure there is no phrase in English for this then please give it as an answer instead of just commenting!

Comment: I think you're trying to include an idiomatic usage that doesn't actually mean what you think it does. [**set the bar (high/low)**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/setting+the+bar+high) - *To establish an expected, required, or desired standard of quality. (Often said of a standard that is constrictive in being either too low or too high).* But your "quit smoking" context isn't actually about having to reach an ***excessively high standard*** to be successful - you're just saying it's ***very difficult*** (and you can't "half quit" or "quarter quit" to give yourself an easier time).

Comment: (Actually, I suppose if you decided that you weren't going to actually stop smoking *completely*, we could say you were "setting the bar low" if you announced, for example, ***I will never smoke in the shower***).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Exactly, I also think the phrase "set the bar high" cannot be used to these kind of cases, but that was the closest thing that I found. My whole question was about trying to find a correct phrase.

Comment: You could talk about a *difficult goal*. This has the advantage of not using a metaphor which can be both misused and misunderstood.

Comment: @simonatrcl If I say "The threshold for quitting smoking is high for me", do you really think it can be misunderstood? I am absolutely sure everybody would understand exactly what I mean, but I would just like to know if there is a better English phrase for that.

Comment: The threshold of something is where it starts and it's height is not usually relevant. Your .sentence *sounds* as though it means that you'd find quitting smoking difficult, but you might also mean that starting to quit smoking is difficult. You are using words not for their literal meaning but for their metaphoric value. Try simpler ones. It is difficult to stop smoking; it is difficult to begin to stop smoking. No ambiguity about either of those.

Comment: @simonatrcl In case of smoking, there is usually no reason to explicitly speak about "beginning to stop smoking". However, in case of running for President the beginning process is such a huge effort that it might be relevant to be explicit about "beginning" and in such a case I would say "There is a high threshold for me to start running for President". Anyway, my point is that one can be explicit even when using the phrase. But my original QUESTION was: what is the correct phrase?

Comment: There is no one correct phrase. There are complicated ways and simple ways and ways in-between. You seem fixated on using complicated ways. Fine; I have no problem with that. But to do so successfully (i.e. with easy understanding by the hearer and no ambiguity) and to do that you need a thorough understanding of the language used and it's idioms. Your question becomes 'explain the English language to me thoroughly, and all it's idioms please', which is a bit broad. The best I can do is say 'Use the simplest expressions (and no simpler)' and that's what I said.

Comment: @simonatrcl Simplicity seems to be relative: To me a generic phrase that applies to the case is more simple than thinking of a separate way of expressing every individual situation which all have essentially the same idea. But I am a system designer used to think ideas on high abstract level so that might explain why we think differently ;)

Comment: Ah c'mon. I've been designing computer systems for 40+ years, and am thoroughly confident with abstraction. Anyway, no more conversation or the mods will get annoyed. Haave a good one!

Comment: *the **threshold*** represents the metaphorical boundary between two "states of being" (smoker and non- / ex-smoker), but the more natural metaphor here is ***The journey of a thousand miles starts with a single step*** - where as we all know, it's that first step that's the hardest to take.